# Convert SmbFile to File Java

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I have the necessity to convert a SmbFile provided by a server that use the SMB protocol into a java File inside my web application. I try to use various solution, but none of these works fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36473193/399435 help?

Comment: Which operating system is this on, what did you try, what happened, what did you want to happen

Comment: I am using a Linux server (Ubuntu distro), and in my webapp I am not able to convert the file inside the server in the Java file format

Comment: What do you mean by "convert" - do you want to download a file from the server? How did the "various solutions" you tried not help you? If you don't say what you tried you will likely get answers that suggest things you already tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Apache Commons IO**: to convert smbfile to java file.

`InputStream is = smbFile.getInputStream();
 File targetFile = new File("yourpath/file.pdf");
 FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, targetFile);`