# Move a file from a non-SMB location to a SMB location in Java

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

How do you move a file from a local non-SMB folder to a SMB location in the server?

Below code doesn't work, but it's something like this what I am after. I am able to authenticate the smb location.

```
String sourceFile="target/abc.xml";
String smbDestinationFile="sharePath/abc/smblocation/xyz.xml";
SmbFile sTargetFile = performAuthenticationAndChecks(destinationFile, domain, domainUsername,
    domainPassword);
Files.move(Paths.get(sourceFile), (Path) sTargetFile);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: jcifs.smb1.smb1.SmbFile cannot be cast to java.nio.file.Path
```

Comment: "doesn't work" Please explain (e.g., show exception) as an update to your post.

Comment: @JeffHolt updated the question with exception

Comment: `Paths.get(sTargetFile.getCanonicalPath())` might work instead of `(Path) sTargetFile`.

Comment: You may indeed have a samba problem but your immediate problem is not at all related to samba. It is merely a data type problem. The title of the question is not correct.

Comment: I don't think its a samba problem as I am able to auth and drop files at the SMB location without any issues.
When I tried using getCanonicalPath() I get something like this:-
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: smb1://sharePath/abc/smblocation/xyz.xml.
Please notice '1' that appeared in the exception after smb.  The actual path is something like this - smb://sharePath/abc/smblocation/xyz.xml.

Comment: I meant Java-Samba problem, not samba problem. That is, after fixing the data type problem, you find something else wrong.

Comment: Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339504/convert-smbfile-to-java-io-file)?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an outdated library. Look for maintained alternatives such as JFileServer or jNQ.